# Installing and publishing npm packages to remote server does not support the UNC path

Tags: npm, cypress, devops, npm-install

I need to install new packages from DevOps on a remote machine for testing in Cypress. Unfortunately, I have a problem with install step, setting the UNC path and the installation is based on the wrong default path C: \ Windows

Is it even possible to install from DevOps to another server?

```
Starting: Install packages
==============================================================================
Task         : npm
Description  : Install and publish npm packages, or run an npm command. Supports npmjs.com and authenticated registries like Azure Artifacts.
Version      : 1.169.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/npm
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" --version"
6.14.10
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" config list"
'\\phasp13jm2\UICypress'
; cli configs
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.14.10 node/v12.20.1 win32 x64"

; environment configs
userconfig = "C:\\agent\\_work\\5\\npm\\1884.npmrc"

; builtin config undefined
prefix = "C:\\Windows\\ServiceProfiles\\NetworkService\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"

; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
; cwd = C:\Windows
; HOME = C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /D /S /C ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install"
'\\phasp13jm2\UICypress'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\package.json'
npm WARN saveError EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Windows\package-lock.json.527580596'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Windows\package.json'
npm WARN Windows No description
npm WARN Windows No repository field.
npm WARN Windows No README data
npm WARN Windows No license field.
```